# Why does this command create an enormously large file?

Tags: io-redirection, cat

I was experimenting today with some append operations and, in my curiosity, ran this (where **file1.txt** was non-empty and **file2.txt** was empty):

```
$ cat file1.txt >> file2.txt >> file1.txt
```

When I saw it taking a while, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end it. By then, **file1.txt** was hundreds of MB in size.

Switching the file names doesn't produce the same effect; only when the files are in this order does the infinite redirection happen. What exactly is going on that causes this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot tell `cat` to use multiple standard out that way, the last redirection takes precedence so:

```
cat file1.txt >> file2.txt >> file1.txt
```

is equivalent to:

```
>> file2.txt ; cat file1.txt >> file1.txt
```

which obviously quickly fills the file system, given the fact the source file being the destination too grows indefinitely provided `file1.txt` is large enough not to be read at once.

Most modern `cat` implementations should detect the recursivity and abort:

Solaris cat:

```
cat: input/output files 'file1.txt' identical
```

Gnu cat:

```
cat: file1.txt: input file is output file
```

They can be fooled anyway with something like:

```
cat < file1.txt | cat | cat  >> file2.txt >> file1.txt
```

A nice not so useless use of cats ...

Comment: That's a lot of cats, meow.

Comment: You made my head spin but you answered my question!

Comment: And when I asked about this on Google+ (didn't get an answer), it automatically tagged my post with **#Cat** and **#Caturday**

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to reproduce this in a Bash shell:

```
# non-empty file1
$ echo 1 > file1.txt

$ cat file1.txt >> file2.txt >> file1.txt 
cat: file1.txt: input file is output file
```

1 file gets created with 0 length but then I get the above message:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml   2 Sep 10 19:35 file1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml   0 Sep 10 19:35 file2.txt
```

Based on @jlliagre's answer I'm not sure why I'm getting the 2 files. It may be dependent on the `cat` implementation.

#### EDIT #1

@jlliagre updated his answer to show this code which he states as equivalent:

```
>> file2.txt ; cat file1.txt >> file1.txt
```

So now I know why I'm getting the empty `file2.txt`. This notation is legal:

```
>> file2.txt
```

And will create an empty file.

Comment: Try again with `file1.txt` starting out non-empty.

Comment: @Gilles - I just re-read that and noticed it, should I see something different, I still get the error? Or are you just saying that b/c the example in my answer is wrong? I fixed the answer BTW.

Comment: @Gilles - that was your downvote, no? Is it just for something specific or lack of value of the answer?

Comment: Not sure why your answer was voted down, +1 for experiencing before answering, something I didn't do myself ...

Comment: +1; thanks for your experimentation! I'm starting to understand redirects and `cat` behavior better.

Comment: Results will vary depending on your shell. ZSH for example does support multiple redirection so parses the command differently.

Comment: @Caleb - if I add a comment at the top that this is Bash specific, is that enough to comply with your comment?